# Java scanner in if functions not working

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

Selecting each option on the menu now works fine (thank you for the help Tarek Salah and dasblinkenlight). The problem now being that when I select an option that requires me to enter a new word (for example option 3 the user must enter the name of a song) it skips over that and goes back to the menu. Does anyone know how to stop that from happening so that the user can actually enter something?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class JukeboxApp { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Jukebox jb = new Jukebox();
    boolean check = false;
    System.out.println("Please enter the corresponding number to perform said action.");
    while ( check == false ) {
        System.out.println("1: Add a song to the JukeBox\n" +
                            "2: Remove a song from the JukeBox\n" +
                            "3: Search for a specific song\n" +
                            "4: Display total price to play all songs\n" +
                            "5: Display the most expensive song\n" +
                            "6: Display the shortest song\n" +
                            "7: Display the most played song\n" +
                            "8: Display all songs in the JukeBox\n" +
                            "9: Display all songs by a specific artist\n" +
                            "10:\n" +
                            "11: Exit the JukeBox");
        int num = sc.nextInt();
        if ( num == 1 ) {
            System.out.println("Please enter the name of the artist");
            String artist = sc.next();
            sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter the title of the song");
            String title = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter the price of the song");
            double price = sc.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Please enter the length of the song");
            double length = sc.nextDouble();
            Song s1 = new Song(artist, title, price, length);
            jb.addSong(s1);
        } else if ( num == 2 ) {
            System.out.println("Please enter the title of the song you would like to remove");
            sc.nextLine();
            jb.removeSong(sc.nextLine());
        } else if ( num == 3 ) {
            System.out.println("Enter the title of the song you are searching for");
            jb.searchSong(sc.nextLine());
        } else if ( num == 4 ) {
            System.out.println(jb.calcTotal());
        } else if ( num == 5 ) {
            System.out.println(jb.showMostExpensive());
        } else if ( num == 6 ) {
            System.out.println(jb.showShortest());
        } else if ( num == 7 ) {
            System.out.println(jb.mostPlayed());
        } else if ( num == 8 ) {
            jb.displaySongs();
        } else if ( num == 9 ) {
            System.out.println("Please enter the artist you are searching for");
            System.out.println(jb.searchArtist(sc.nextLine()));
        } else if ( num == 10 ) {
            System.out.println("");
        } else if ( num == 11 ) {
            System.out.println("Thank you for using my JukeBox.");
            check = true;
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: use if {} elseif{} ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this does not work is that you may be calling `sc.nextInt()` multiple times, when you expect your user to enter only one value.

You should store the result in a variable, and use that variable in all your `if` statements. Alternatively, you could use a `switch` statement.

```
var userEntry = sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine(); // skip to the end of the line
if ( userEntry  == 1 ) {
    ...
} else if ( userEntry  == 2 ) {
    ...
} else if ( userEntry  == 3 ) {
    ...
} else ...
```

or

```
var userEntry = sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine(); // skip to the end of the line
switch ( userEntry ) {
    case 1:
        ...
    break;
    case 2:
        ...
    break;
    case 3:
        ...
    break;
    default:
        ...
    break;
}
```

Comment: That works for selecting what I want to do but now when it runs one of the if functions that require me to enter a new word, it won't let me and just exits the if and loops back around. For example, option 3: The user should be able to search for a song but it skips over that and goes back to the menu.

Comment: @Michael_D That's because `nextLine()` gets the end-of-line that you enter right after the menu digit. You need to call `nextLine()` after `nextInt()` (see my edit).

Answer (score 0):

Change if to else if and take input `nextInt()` for one time in each loop

```
int num = sc.nextInt()
if (num  == 1 ) {

}
else if ( num == 2 ) {

}
else if ( num == 3 ) {

}
 ....
```

Comment: That works for selecting what I want to do but now when it runs one of the if functions that require me to enter a new word, it won't let me and just exits the if and loops back around.

For example, option 3: The user should be able to search for a song but it skips over that and goes back to the menu.